# Bukkit server - I can connect but no-one else can

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods, minecraft-bukkit

Title sums it up nicely. This problem is odd though; I know it is not an issue with networking (so I've port forwarded correctly etc.) because I can run a vanilla server and everyone can connect fine. When I run my Tekkit Classic bukkit server though, I can connect via localhost but my friend gets "Failed to login; bad login" and my server log is

`[INFO] /88.35.654.33 Lost connection`

Server.properties is configured correctly, and I'm running in online mode.

What could be the problem?

Comment: try setting ur server to offline mode

Comment: @Ender what effect does that have? Surely I need it in online mode in order for people to connect from the outside?

Comment: Negative, offline\online mode involves your server talking with the Mojang servers to find out if your players have an actual account and whatnot. More often than not 'bad login' is a result of this 'handshaking' process taking too long. Setting your server to offline mode does have its problems, however, if your only playing with friends that you know, these will not come up. I highly advise you DO NOT put your server in offline mode if it is a public server.

Comment: @Ender Thank you very much for the advice, it's a server for me and a friend to play tekkit on, so obviously there will be no issues with offline. I presume the problems with public servers are hacked accounts for griefers etc. so there will be no problems. Any more I should know about online/offline mode in my current circumstances?

Comment: Other than the concept of 'hacked accounts' and people being able to theoretically login as 'other people' there are no other issues that I am aware of. And of course, for a private server, none of these issues are actually an issue. If it works come back and let me know and I'll post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Ender Thanks for everything. If you post an answer I'll be happy to accept it. One thing though: how come my vanilla server worked and my bukkit one didn't?

Comment: everything I know about the subject points toward your bukkit\vanilla situation being coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your server in offline mode. Offline\online mode involves your server talking with the Mojang servers to find out if your players have an actual account and whatnot. More often than not 'bad login' is a result of this 'handshaking' process taking too long.

Setting your server to offline mode does have its problems however, it allows people with hacked clients to join your server, and it also allows people with some java knowledge to join your server posing as other players. This can lead to some severe griefing. That said, if your only playing with friends that you know then I don't think these issues will come up. I highly advise you DO NOT put your server in offline mode if it is a public server but other than that, it's worth a try.